# Get iOS (iPhone) Battery information using desktop command line over USB connection

Tags: ios, iphone, command-line, battery

I have already tried libmobiledevice tool but it is only returning limited info for battery. I am looking for more detail info on iPhone battery like battery current capacity, current temperature, current voltage, battery level, etc

From command line we can get the battery details of iOS phones using libimobiledevice tools.
Inside the tools use the command:

`./ideviceinfo -q com.apple.mobile.battery`

It will return something like:

```
BatteryCurrentCapacity: 30 
BatteryIsCharging: true 
ExternalChargeCapable: true 
ExternalConnected: true 
FullyCharged: false 
GasGaugeCapability: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to hook into the iPhone's internal processes to get more details... such as with Frida. Since some of this information is displayed in the settings app, you can probably get it from hooking the SpringBoard process. So, to do this over USB... you would likely need an SSH-over-USB tunnel.